# adding new column in admin/sales/order/ view page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php-7

I tried this code but it is giving a column at the end of the table, I want this column at the starting of the table (product image)

```
file : app\code\Product\image\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
     <referenceBlock name="order_items">
         <arguments>
             <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="custom_item_column" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Image</item>
             </argument>
         </arguments>
         <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
                  <arguments>
                    <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="product_img" xsi:type="string" translate="true">product_img</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
             <action method="setTemplate">
                 <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product_Image::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
             </action>
         </referenceBlock>
     </referenceBlock>
 </body>
</page>
```

```
file: app\code\Product\image\view\adminhtml\templates\order\view\items\renderer\default.html
```

```
<?php /** @var \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer $block */ ?>
<?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
<?php $block->setPriceDataObject($_item) ?>
<tr>
    <?php $i = 0;
    $columns = $block->getColumns();
    $lastItemNumber = count($columns) ?>
    <td>
        <?php $product =  $_item->getProduct();?>
        <?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();?>

        <?php  $imagewidth=200;
        $imageheight=200;
        $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
        $image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'small_image')->setImageFile($product->getSmallImage())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl();
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>" />
    </td>
    <?php foreach ($columns as $columnName => $columnClass):?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <td class="<?= /* @noEscape */ $columnClass ?><?= /* @noEscape */ ($i === $lastItemNumber ? ' last' : '') ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getColumnHtml($_item, $columnName) ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```

```
registration.php

<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Product_Image',
    __DIR__
);
```

```
module.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Product_Image">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

it is working but the thing is i want the product image column at the starting of the column in sales/order/view/ page

thanks

Answer (score 0):

add this line in xml before end of body

```
<move element="default_order_items_renderer" destination="order_items" before="-"/>
```

Comment: i added above line after end of </referenceBlock> (i.e, above </body>) but it is giving                ```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Renderer for type "configurable" does not exist.```` this error.

Answer (score 0):

Then update code as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
     <referenceBlock name="order_items">
         
         <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
                  <arguments>
                    <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="product_img" xsi:type="string" translate="true">product_img</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
             <action method="setTemplate">
                 <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product_Image::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
             </action>
         </referenceBlock>
            <arguments>
             <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="custom_item_column" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Image</item>
             </argument>
         </arguments>
     </referenceBlock>
 </body>
</page>
```

Comment: it gives same result as my code rajesh

Comment: oppss..then you have to figure out..

Answer (score 0):

Override vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml file in your custom module

like Vendor_name/Module_name/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

Than you see columns and then simply add your column using this

`<item name="product_img" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Image</item>`

Than add value of your column using this

```
<item name="product_img" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-product_img</item>
```

After this add your phtml file

```
<block class="Vendor_name\Module_name\Block\Image" name="product_img" template="Vendor_name_Module_name::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml" group="column"/>
```

Block file Vendor_name\Module_name\Block\Image

```
namespace Vendor_name\Module_name\Block;
```

class Image extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

{

```
protected $_orderModel;    

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderModel,
    array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_orderModel = $orderModel;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

Run cmd and check in sales order view

I hope this will help you