# How to move order items column in Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, orders, column

I want to move order item custom column after qty column in admin. So how can i move it. Can you see my screenshot.

[image]

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

Check link for how to add new column in sales order view

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/354795/99531

If not done with this please send you sales_order_view.xml code